# Ionic App With Crosswalk Compile, Install But Doesn't Open

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've installed Crosswalk Lite (2.4.0)
Had build problems(aapt) with Android 7.0.0, the stack community oriented me to use this plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --fetch
```

The build process ran just fine.
It generates 5 debub apk's (arm7, arm64, armbi, x86, x86_64)

My phone is an arm64, but I tried all the five with no sucess.

**Anyone knows a way to run on an emulator and get a log of whats happening?**

With Chrome Remote Devices feature I could not get information cause the webview don't even launchs

Comment: have you tried adb logcat to get the system logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an answer [here](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/crosswalk_lite.html) :

> Supported platforms Lite is currently Android only and does not
>   support shared mode Lite only supports 32-bit builds for x86 and ARM.
>   x86_64 and ARM64 are not yet supported.

So It seems you will have to use the full version of crosswalk.

In my app I use the plugin ***cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview*** and it generates me only two apks : armv7 and x86.

I remember testing lite version by using

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --variable XWALK_MODE="lite"
```

but quickly gave up because the app was not working as expected.